# Efficiently adding large group of classes to a map array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-c++, c-preprocessor

So I have a huge amount of classes (20+ that I want to store into a map array as such:

```
mapArray['ClassName'] = new ClassName();
```

I thought about doing something like

```
App::setup() {
    mapArray['ClassName1'] = new ClassName1();
    mapArray['ClassName2'] = new ClassName2();
    mapArray['ClassName3'] = new ClassName3();
}
```

However I think that is inefficient. I was thinking on how I would go about doing this, I was thinking to use preprocessor directives. Something like this

```
#define DECLARE_CLASS(ClassName)
    mapArray[ClassName] = new ClassName();
```

However, with this approach I would still need to to call that multiple time within the same function or something.

How would I go about adding all the classes to the same array but without calling the same code multiple time within the same function? So that the code isn't repetitive.

Comment: presumably these classes are all derived from a common base class?

Comment: Yes they are all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using

```
App::setup() {
    mapArray['ClassName1'] = new ClassName1();
    mapArray['ClassName2'] = new ClassName2();
    mapArray['ClassName3'] = new ClassName3();
}
```

is not a good idea (even after you fix the incorrect syntax of trying to use single quotes to define a string). It breaks the [Open/Closed Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle). If you want to add `ClassNameN` to your system, you have to come back to modify a working function.

It's better to use a registration mechanism. Declare a function, `registerObject`, as:

```
App::registerObject(std::string const& name, BaseClass* ptr);
```

and implement it as:

```
static std::map<std::string, BaseClass*>& getClassMap()
{
   static std::map<std::string, BaseClass*> theMap;
   return theMap;
}

App::registerObject(std::string const& name, BaseClass* ptr)
{
   getClassMap()[name] = ptr;
}
```

and then, in the source file that contains the implementation of `ClassNameN`, make sure to call

```
App::registerObject("ClassNameN", new ClassNameN());
```

One way to register:

1. Use a helper class called `Initializer`, which is defined in the .cpp file.
2. Make the call to `App::registerObject` in the constructor of `Initializer.
3. Create a file scoped `static` instance of `Initializer` in the .cpp file

ClassName1.cpp:

```
#include "ClassName1.hpp"

// You can use anonymous namespace but I prefer to use a named
// namespace. It makes names of the typeinfo object clearer.

namespace ClassName1NS
{
   struct Initializer
   {
      Initializer();
   };
}

using namespace ClassName1NS;

static Initializer initializer

Initializer::Initializer()
{
   App::registerObject("ClassName1", new ClassName1());
}
```

Comment: Yea that is similar to how I was planning on it. I know I shouldn't make the objects array public, wasn't planning on it. Anyway, I can't call registerObject in the global space, can I? I mean I have to call it in a function, correct?

Comment: Correct. I use a helper class in the .cpp file called `Initializer`. In the constructor of the class, I make such calls and make sure that a `static` object of type `Initializer` is constructed in the .cpp file.

Comment: Could you update your answer with a detail explanation on a helper class and a initializer please?